# I want to find difference between two CARDS in POWER BI, I can't use measure because i applied filters on the cards

Tags: powerbi

[image: Values in two cards]

[image: Filters applied for 2nd row]
[image: Filters applied for 1st row]

I have posted the images, with the filter i have applied to the rows. I would get the difference value as 10 .

Answer (score 2):

[This link](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/A-card-for-a-measure/m-p/665054#M319813) offers guidance on how to compare two filtered cards.
Summary:

1. Re-create table twice for each set of cards ([How to create calculated table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-calculated-tables#:%7E:text=Just%20like%20other%20Power%20BI,visualizations%20just%20like%20other%20fields)).
2. Create a measure for each card, e.g. Measure1 = CALCULATE(SUM(TableForCard1[Col]))
3. Create a measure for the difference, e.g. Diff = [Measure1]-[Measure2]

Answer (score 1):

You could create measures for each individual card that includes the filters that you added to them.  And then you would just have to subtract the two measures from each other to get your last value.

Comment: thanks for the response, can you tell me how to write the measure for this ?

Comment: @kapardhiguda111 Can you supply examples of your data?  I would need the table/column names to help you.  Here is a link to creating COUNTS with filters though: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/countx-function-dax.